# Visual Studio Online Continuous Integration Build fails unexpectedly

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I've been using Visual Studio Online's Gated check-in to build and deploy my web API app to an Azure Website for a while now. Yesterday I added a few features to my app, and triggered a build after check-in, and it failed with the following response.

```
Exception Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path (type ArgumentNullException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I really don't know what is going on as this is clearly not my code and it worked a few weeks ago.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing a build of your code prior to the changes? If you build based on the last successful build changeset.

Comment: Yup, that was the first thing I did, i'm quite confident this isn't something I've caused.

Comment: So building old changesets that previously had a successful build now failed?

Comment: Are you also saying that you only build every few weeks?

Comment: A build is triggered on every check-in, I haven't checked-in code in a few weeks is what I meant.

Comment: So building old changesets that previously had a successful build now failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recreated the publish profile to fix the error:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso/

You could as well switch to TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml template manually, looks like the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template isn't compatible with latest updates.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, indirectly.... I created a new source controlled project in VS, and migrated my code across.

Answer (score 2):

Could you provide more information on where in the build it failed? The callstack only contains details from Windows Workflow. If we could see what part of the build is actually hitting the error, we might be able to provide more help.

A recent update is the most likely cause, but we need to know more to isolate what is causing the issue.

#### Diagnostics Error Log

```
If a Compilation Exception Occurred
   Rethrow Compilation Exception
           Exception Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path (type ArgumentNullException) 
           Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) 
                                  at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) 
                                  at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: you're gonna need to help me out here, how best can I show you what part of the build is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jason Prickett I have the same error but no additional information is in the logs. Looked at Diagnostics tab too, this error is the last entry after build and test run completed with this label: If a Compilation Exception Occurred 
Rethrow Compilation Exception. There's no deployment error reported but deployment didn't happen so could be related to deployment.

Comment: The same settings worked on 21 April, today was the first build since then and failed. Tasks in NuGet.targets file are imported like posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20690589/3285954

Comment: Added the error message with workflow action - seems like `ExecuteActivityWorkItem` is crashing. We just had to update our templates to **TFS 2013** to workaround a recent VSO upgrade in Q2 2015. We also noticed all the oAuth connectors between Azure and our VSO were disconnected. We had to disconnect/reconnect to establish the trust again. This will create the new workflow for you if you delete the existing TFS 2012 one (**[websitename]_CD**).