# TFS build error while trying to build

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I did some code changes in my code like assigning values to Nullable byte type variables.

Now when i try to build my application I get a error message and the build does not succeed. I am using visual studio 2012. Here is the error message which i get's

```
Exception Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path (type ArgumentNullException)
Exception Stack Trace:at    System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Does any one else experienced the same? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding from the last good build? That would tell you is it was the changes or infrastructure.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661943/build-on-tfs-2013-failed-but-okay-locally

Comment: I have the same problem, but without the CodeTaskFactory error mentioned in Morten's link (and I don't have the nuget targets file mentioned there, either). I only have the ArgumentNullException - no idea where to start to diagnose this...